# Router link to scroll on top if its already on that route

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routerlink

Lets say I'm at the **bottom** of my **home page** and I click on my logo, Now because the logo routes me to my home page and **that I'm already at my home page**. It should scroll me to the top of the page. How do I implement this.

*Homepage Component HTML*

```
<a routerLink="">
  <img src="../assets/Logo.png" alt="" />
</a>
```

*App Routing Module*

```
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomeComponent,
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Scrolling to top is, if you have a "normal" page, basically done with:

```
window.scrollTo(0, 0);
```

But you have to recognize that a routing event happened either. So put this code into your `ngOnInit()`.

```
this.router.events.subscribe((event: Event) => {
    if (event instanceof NavigationEnd) {
        window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    }
}
```